# Time remaining using PHP & MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I currently have a website that uses tokens which can be redeemed and these tokens are valid for a specific amount of time. For example, I redeem a token and that token grants me access for 24 hours.

Now, what I would like to know is how would I best create a system that checks if the token (time of the token) is expired?

I was thinking of putting the current time in the MySQL database whenever someone redeems a token and then make a PHP script that periodically checks if 24, 48 etc. hours have passed and then deletes the token from the database.

Any ideas or tips are highly appreciated.

Comment: if you are dealing within specific time zone, can set the server time first like for London `date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');` and then save token time in MySQL database, later you can call the token saved time and can  calculate difference with current date time `$date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');` and do the rest to  and set if else statament

Comment: Thanks @shehary for the tips. I think that you have answered my question. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If the token stays available (through session for example), you can just re-validate/check the token on every request.

```
SELECT * FROM `tokens`
WHERE `token` = 'yourtoken' AND `date_redeemed` >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY;
```

If you do  not get any results, the token has expired.

If the token is not available for every new request, your own suggestion is fine too. You can do that in the same fashion:

```
UPDATE `tokens`
SET `expired` = NOW()
WHERE `date_redeemed` >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

You could probably even run it every 1 or 2 hours, depending on how many tokens there are. I would do that with a `cron` job.

Answer (score 0):

Put the timestamp of expiration in the token itself. Depending on how you manage your tokens you might also want to put in a cryptographic checksum that covers both the random and timestamp to prevent tampering. E.g.

```
$token = $randString . $timestamp . $checksum;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer @eborbob. I would also like to the post the time remaining for the token. Any ideas on how this would work?